# How to enable Google Classroom courseWorkList

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I've been testing the Google Classroom Api and can't seem to get the courseWorkList method to run getting a caller error

I've basically cut and pasted code from the reference and it works if i remove the classCourseWork line. Otherwise I get a "The caller does not have permission" error. I've enabled the API services, approved it to run, etc.  Any help in getting this one sorted?

```
 function listCourses() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    pageSize: 10
  };
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs);
  var courses = response.courses;

  if (courses && courses.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
      var course = courses[i];
        var classCourseWork = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(course.id);
      }
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', course.name, course.id);

  } else {
    Logger.log('No courses found.');
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code work on my end, try checking if the caller have access or enrolled to that course. You might want to check this open [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6753) even a teacher cannot access the coursework (or the students' turned-in assignments) in their course, getting the same permission error.

Comment: Are you running it as a student account or as a teacher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code, here are the scenarios:

As a student:

Your code is working fine.

[image]
As a teacher:

I've also received "The caller does not have permission" error.
[image]

You might want to check this open [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6753), that a teacher cannot access the coursework (or the students' turned-in assignments) in their course, getting the same permission error. It was updated and was filed a ticket internally, we can follow this ticket to be updated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Not necessarily a solution but it pinpoints the problem and points to the proper place to keep track of the issue.

Comment: Glad the info helps

Answer (score 0):

Does this thread sound like the same issue? [Http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796630/google-classroom-apps-script-coursework-list-permission-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796630/google-classroom-apps-script-coursework-list-permission-error)

Comment: Similar but the question is not answered. I have updated my question showing the relevant API's